# certbot nginx doesn't finish

Tags: django, nginx, certbot

question regarding letsencrypt.org certbot.

Whenever I run the `certbot --nginx` command, it never finishes the process.

Full output (running as root):

```
$ certbot --nginx --agree-tos --redirect --uir --hsts --staple-ocsp --must-staple -d <DOMAINS> --email <EMAIL>
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for <DOMAIN>
http-01 challenge for <DOMAIN>
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django:50
Cleaning up challenges
nginx restart failed:
b''
b''
```

Running `certbot certificates`:

```
$ certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No certs found.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The only thing where I messed up was not properly configuring my DNS before running certbot the first time (messed up my A record, et al; I'm new at this :P), however I don't know what to do moving forward; this is my first web-server so I'm still in a bit of a learning curve. I'm not sure if this is a configuration error, or something else.

For info, I'm running a DigitalOcean Django/Ubuntu 16.04 droplet (only edited /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, to change server_name). Will update below for any additional info needed; thanks in advance. ^_^

=========================================================================

edit 1.
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django

```
    upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;

                proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show us the content of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django` - that is where the error is.

Comment: @solarissmoke added

Comment: you cand check this logs for system messags related to nginx and cerbot (letsencrypt) `less /var/log/syslog` `less /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to specify two `default_server` directives on the same port. This is invalid - there can be only one default server. Changing your configuration as follows should fix your issue:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

You can also remove the `ipv6only` directive as this is the default anyway.